# The puzzle from ____

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

We’ve had some tough puzzles on this site, but this is the puzzle from... well, if I told you, it wouldn’t *register* as a puzzle now.

Maybe you can work it out for yourself:

> HGT - 271
>   T 732 LI
>   UM 21(13)
>   H 132 QE
>
> LS 11(23)
>   11 - (83) - XN
>   SLU - (59)1
>   L 213 FM

## Complete the title

Hints for the final steps:

> BIDMAS (or BODMAS, PEMDAS, whatever you know it as)

and

> °'"

Comment: The Puzzle from _Beastly Gerbil's brain_ :P

Comment: @ABcDexter hmmm suppose so :P

Comment: Also if this helps: there is a clue in the body of the text as to the first step

Comment: @ABcDexter well a specific word, but yes

Comment: Is the hint **Complete the title**? :P

Comment: @boboquack damn, how did you get that? I thought I made that really, really subtle!!! ;)

Comment: "Hell". Because it's always "Hell" after "something something from..."

Comment: I figured the hint was "register" even before the edit... I think I know what it's hinting at, as well...

Comment: If you google "hgt 271" the first hit is *this* puzzle

Comment: @EngineerToast of course I'm the first hit on google ;)

Comment: @Marius you were more correct than you realised, see the correct answer below :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil. I knew it. My psychic sense was right. I just couldn't prove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is

> The puzzle from **hell**

[F1Krazy's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50056/18250) states that this looks like registration plates. Bouncing off this idea, [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_European_Union) has a list of EU registration plates (not UN as initially stated. OP Edit: Sorry bout that!)

Taking the country abbreviation of each plate gives:

> HGT - 271  -> Finland -> FIN 
>   T 732 LI  -> Austria -> A 
>   UM 21(13)  -> Luxembourg -> L 
>   H 132 QE  -> Austria -> A
>
> LS 11(23)  -> Luxembourg -> L 
>   11 - (83) - XN  -> Portugal -> P 
>   SLU - (59)1  -> Hungary -> H 
>   L 213 FM  -> Austria -> A
>
> Which gives us the clue: FINAL ALPHA

[Gareth McCaughan points out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50053/the-puzzle-from/50076?noredirect=1#comment153285_50073) that the FINAL ALPHA(BETIC CHARACTERS), or last letters give 'TIMES NUM'

[Donnelle's idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50076/18250) is to multiply each digit, which is close, but taking into account the brackets we get:

> 271 => 14 
>   732 => 42 
>   21(13) => 26 
>   132 => 6 
>   
>   11(23) => 23 
>   11 - (83) => 83 
>   (59)1 => 59 
>   213 => 6

The second hint implies these are latitude and longitude coordinates. The first number of each in A1Z26 translates to N and W, giving us the coordinates.

> N 42° 26' 6", W 83° 59' 6"

If you look up these coordinates you get:

> [image]

The location of [Hell, Michigan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell,_Michigan). (So Donnelle was technically right in her guess.) So it is in fact,

> **The puzzle from hell.**

Comment: well, the final alpha(betic character) of each one spells out TIMES NUM...

Comment: How do you distinguish the 3 letters and 3 digits in the Finnish and Hungarian licence plates?

Comment: @jarnbjo I narrowed it down to a few, and then I was informed the - is important which narrowed it further to those two, at which point it was just fillling in what made sense because of all the other plates/abbreviations I had

Comment: If the hyphen in the question is relevant, then Austria is wrong. There are no hyphens in Austrian licence plates.

Comment: That's a good point, I imagine Gerbil would want to fix that because with or without the hyphen, Austria is the only one in that page that follows the A 123 BC pattern.

Comment: @jarnbjo thanks for pointing that out, will update

Comment: Super interesting puzzle, although it took some group effort and help from the OP, still fun to grind out the solution

Answer (score 3):

I believe each of the alphanumeric codes is

> A vehicle registration number (hence the "register" hint in the title).

My first instinct, therefore, is to

> Look up the registration numbers to see what locales they would be valid in.

I don't think I have enough time to do that in my lunch break but hopefully that's enough of a starting point.

Comment: All info you can get off Wikipedia

Answer (score 3):

Using n_palum's answer, and Gareth's comment, I think the answer is:

> The puzzle from **hell**

Because:

> When you multiply the digits in each row together, you get
>  271 => 14
>  732 => 42
>  21(13) => 6
>  132 => 6
>  11(23) => 6
>  11 - (83) => 24
>  (59)1 => 45
>  213 => 6
>
>   And 666 is the number traditionally associated with hell.

Comment: Interesting although I am not sure if that's exactly what he's going for

Comment: Well, it seems like there are co-ordinates hidden in there.

Comment: Update: Still multiplying only - your answers should now be: 14, 42, 26, 6, 23, 83, 59, 6.